# Samsung Galaxy Note will not Turn On after Android 4.1.1 Upgrade

Tags: updates, samsung-galaxy-note

I have downloaded Jelly Bean 4.1.1 for my Galaxy Note N7000.

While updating through the phone, it shut down and now it is not working.I cannot turn it on.

The battery was about 40%. I guess it is because of the battery level. What can I do to sort this out?

Comment: Please provide more details. Are you rooted? What do you mean by `updating through the phone`? Is it an OTA update?

Comment: I pressed power butten, volume key up and home key buttens simultaniousl. Then, I applied to the update in internal SD card. Then, It started updating. After that, when 20 % of the update was done, the phone shouted down. As the result it is now not working.

Comment: Some other tablets have two levels of shutdown, and the lower one requires holding the power button down until it turns on (about 20 seconds on my Asus Eee Pad).

Comment: I even held it for 1 mins :) it didnt help